# how do I make my node.js app change its working directory

Tags: node.js, fs, dirname

I had my app initially at a folder D:/nodeapps/zup, I recently moved it to D:/nodeapps/zup/0.0.2, Whenever I try using __dirname,  I keep getting the error

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\nodejsapps\zup\json\offers.json'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'd:\\nodejsapps\\zup\\json\\offers.json' }
```

I understand very well that __dirname is pointing to the old folder. How do I change __dirname to point inside 0.0.2

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Can you please describe what is offers.json ?
I think if you move your node_modules and package.json inside "D:/nodeapps/zup/0.0.2" it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

process.chdir('/path/to/wherever/you/want/');

This will change the working directory but it seems that you need to find out why __dirname is giving you the wrong path and fix that.